# How do I get the symbol ` (the one to the left of #1 on a british keyboard) in latex?

Tags: latex

I am trying to get the symbol `` ` ``, as it is, in latex.  However, I am ending up with a single quotation mark instead of the symbol itself. Could you please let me know how I can achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\textasciigrave` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\textasciigrave 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thank you!!

Comment: @prananna You're welcome!